# How to handling multiple files upload golang revel

Tags: file, go, file-handling, revel

I'm trying to handle multiple files upload in `golang-revel`. [Here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sevki/revel/samples/upload/app/controllers) is the documentation that i follow.

This is what i've tried

**HTML**

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" multiple class="form-control" placeholder="Select Files">
```

**GO**

```
var (
        files [][]byte
    )
c.Params.Bind(&files, "file")
// c.Validation.MinSize(files, 1).Message("You cannot submit less than 1 files")
c.Validation.MaxSize(files, 3).Message("You cannot submit more than 3 files")
filenames := ""

    file_ext := ""

    for i, _ := range files {

        filenames += tools.ReplaceName(c.Params.Files["files[]"][i].Filename, fmt.Sprint(c.Params.Files["file"][0].Size), true) + "|"
        file_ext += strings.Replace(filenames[strings.LastIndex(filenames, "."):], ".", "", -1) + "|"
        print("INSIDE FOR LOOP")
        print(filenames)
        print(file_ext)

    }

    print("FILE NAMES AND EXT")
    print(filenames)
    print(file_ext)
```

The Problem is the file is `c.Params.Bind(&files, "file")` produced empty `[]` array. But it worked when i tried to upload single file.

Why when i upload multiple files it can't receive any ?